# Using Northing/Easting point to match nearest Geometry data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, geometry

I've been provided with a shapefile, which contains data for roads in a given area in the UK.

I've used a [ShapeFile uploader](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools.aspx) to upload the shapefile to a SQL Server 2008 table, which is great.

So now I have records stored for each row with appropriate Geometry data.  This consists of LineString data made up of multiple Northing as Easting points )

For example:

> LINESTRING (338743.914 373987.193, 338750.531 373977.156, 338753.812 373973.375, 338758.156 373969.625, 338760.094 373968.156, 338762.719 373966.969, 338765.469 373966.594, 338771.125 373966.938, 338781.281 373969.844)

Now, I want to create a query so I can match a records in the database based on Northing and Easting values I supply?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with spatial stuff, but you'll probably want to start reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) -- there should be examples in there somewhere.